# Set property that isn't declared

Tags: php

Can you call an attribute "example" without declaring it? Why this code still work? And why echo only print once not twice.

```
class SetMissing {
        public function __set($name, $value) {
            echo "_SET";
            $this->$name = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }
    }
    $obj = new SetMissing();
    $obj->example = "<strong>hello</strong>";
    echo $obj->example . PHP_EOL ;
    $obj->example = "<strong>hello</strong>";
    echo $obj->example;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`__set`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) is a magic function that writes to inaccessible or non-existing properties. You can access inaccessible or non-existing properties with the magic [`__get`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) method.

With inline comments:

```
$obj = new SetMissing(); // Create object
$obj->example = "hello"; // Propery doesn't exist. Call __set, create a property with name "example" and value "hello" on the object
echo $obj->example . PHP_EOL ; // Access the property because it exists
$obj->example = "hello"; // Overwrite value
echo $obj->example; // Access it again
```

Also, [your example does echo twice](https://3v4l.org/lFUFS)?

Comment: Thank you very much Loek. The code only prints out the word "_SET" once. I dont see it printing out the message inside the Magic method twice. Because we called the magic twice, didnt we ?

Comment: Nope. Only the first time. Then the property is actually added to the object and you can access/write it like you normally would.

Comment: If the magic method only called once, how can the code filter out the HTML code twice i.e  filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); ?

Comment: It doesn't? I removed the tags in my example, sorry! Check here for the behavior you expect: https://3v4l.org/MfilA

Comment: If I remove the code inside the magic function, it throws the error ?https://paiza.io/projects/e/AaYdy-BuD2AWP2RZPHfj_Q. If I run the original code on my computer, php 7.2, I can see that it prints out like this "_SEThello hello". PHP compiler is so buggy, I think.

Comment: Why is it buggy? Sorry but your comments and code make perfect sense? Remove code that actually sets properties? Sure, then you're getting undefined properties. `__set` is called magically, but if it doesn't have a body, it isn't going to do anything. In your example, check the output, it says "_SET" twice, which is exactly what should happen with that code. You don't seem to understand what `__set` or your code does. That's fine, but I can't think of a better way to explain it than I did. Removing parts of your code has consequences, that isn't due to compiler errors but to dead code.

Comment: Hi Luke, What I am trying to explain is that if I remove one line of code // $this->$name = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); and leave the (echo"_SET") in the function. I then encounter an error. What could be the reason?

Comment: Because that line is actually setting the property. If you don't set the property, how does PHP know what you're trying to call when you do `$obj->example`?

Comment: THANK YOU Loek for your patience, I understand now. The confusion lies in the behaviour of the _set magic function. If the attribute is predefined in the class, like in this example [https://paiza.io/projects/e/otOORBtly41-5Uu3N0cF3A], then the magic method will be called TWICE. However, for undefined attribute, it is only called ONCE.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please tick as an answer so others can benefit :)